# Proving $ \mathbf{x} \perp \mathbf{y} \implies ||\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}||^2 =||\mathbf{x}||^2+||\mathbf{y}||^2 $

Tags: real-analysis

The proof looks like this

$$||\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}||^2$$
$$= (\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}) \cdot (\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y})$$
$$=\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}\cdot\mathbf{y}+2(\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{y})$$
$$=||\mathbf{x}||^2+||\mathbf{y}||^2$$

I do not understand what happens after the second equality sign.

Comment: Can you explain the context of the equation a little bit ?

Comment: If $\mathbf{x} \perp \mathbf{y}$, then $\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y} = 0$

Comment: @StinkingBishop This was actually what I was asking for! Please post this comment as an answer so I can accept this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scalar (dot) product is distributive with respect to addition, which means that you can multiply $x+y$ with $x+y$ by multiplying "each with each" just like in arithmetic. Note also it is symmetrical ($x\cdot y=y\cdot x$) - that is where we get $2(x\cdot y)$. Now you can use the fact that $x\perp y$ means $x\cdot y=0$ to finish the proof.

Also please don't fail to appreciate that the statement you're proving here is one possible statement of ... Pythagoras' theorem!

Comment: It's not a proof of Pythagoras's theorem at all! It uses the identity $||\mathbf{x}||^2=\mathbf{x.x}$, which is a _consequence_ of Pythagoras's theorem. So your claim is circular.

Comment: @TonyK I know ... I may have overstepped the limit of being rigorous, but wanted the OP to feel good about what they have actually proven. (Even if they used Pythagoras' theorem during the proof, the result *is* a possible statement of Pythagoras' theorem, that is what I wanted to be appreciated here). I can certainly delete that last sentence if you think it does more harm than good...

Comment: Nah, leave it in. Our comments tell the story.

Comment: @TonyK Made a small edit anyways, hope it removes your main concern here.

Answer (score 0):

By definition
$$x\perp y\iff x\cdot y=0$$
So the mixed term cancels and you are left with the squares.